# Offline tiled map web app

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers-2, html

I'm not sure whether to post this here or on Stackoverflow, as it's sort of a crossover. Let me give it a try.

In the proposed HTML5 standard, there's the option of storing web application data in a local cache using a [cache manifest](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html). I am looking to use this technique for an offline tiled web map application and did a quick prototype [here](http://lima.schaaltreinen.nl/mvexel/cachemanifest/index.html) based on a standard install of Geoserver.

I just ripped the OpenLayers client page that is generated from one of the default layers and changed the `<html>` tag to

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="cache.manifest">
```

And created the file `cache.manifest` which simply reads

```
CACHE MANIFEST
http://lima.schaaltreinen.nl:8080/
```

Which should, in my limited understanding of the matter, locally cache everything that loads from that URL: all tiles and the OpenLayers JS. In fact, upon first call in Firefox, it does ask me to allow local storage, but when I hit refresh - either online or offline - the page croaks stating that the OpenLayers object is not defined. Looks like it hasn't loaded the OpenLayers JS.

Anyone successfully did a functioning offline OpenLayers-based tiled web map app? Or hints on how to investigate this further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be interested in the projects [Maps on a Stick](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2010/oct/02/maps-stick-version-2-released) and MapBox iPad. (disclaimer: designed the former, involved in the latter. however, both are BSD-licensed, and the underlying tile format, termed "`.mbtiles`", is SQL-based.)

Maps on a Stick is an offline OpenLayers map. The main reasoning for going with a portable database/server instead of client side storage is that using browsers as large data storage isn't quite worked out and populating and indexing the cache can be costly.

Comment: Interesting solution, not what I was thinking about but it looks workable. How easy or difficult is it to load MapBox / Maps on a Stick with custom tile layers?

Comment: It's relatively simple: there are a few tools - a C-based importer ( https://github.com/developmentseed/mb_tiles_importer ), a version of gdal2tiles that outputs mbtiles ( https://github.com/developmentseed/gdal2mb ), and an upcoming GUI tool.

Answer (score 4):

Think you will need to create your own **tilecache** on 'localhost' see http://code.google.com/p/cumberland/wiki/TilePyramiderAndOpenLayers

Examples

```
    Using vmap
    http://localhost:8081/vmap0/levelzero/0/0.png
    The tile near the middle of the tile set in the third zoom level of vmap0.
    http://localhost:8081/vmap0/leveltwo/3/4.png
    The tile near the middle of the tile set in the fifth zoom level of landsat2000.
    hhttp://localhost:8081/vmap0/landsat2000/1/8500/8500.png
Source:
    The tile at the origin of the tile set in the first zoom level of basemap.
    http://www.osgeo.org/services/basemap/L1/0/0.png
```

Note: must not have spaces

Comment: This is useful but requires a local web server, which might not always be feasible, e.g. when you want it to run on an iPhone / iPad. In general, I am looking to achieve this without any requirements on the client side other than a HTML5/cache manifest savvy web browser.

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html

Comment: I linked to that page in the original question already. I know this is the way to go, but I am trying to find out if it's feasible at all.

Answer (score 3):

One complexity that seems to show up in articles about this is that:

> Note that the MIME type of the manifest file is text/cache-manifest.

And the examples all seem to list specific files to cache (but I may need to read further).

Comment: That's one thing that is not clear to me: whether you need to whitelist specific concrete URLs or you can use URL prefixes. I have not been able to test this yet. Anyone who has?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe another approach: Geopublisher http://www.geopublishing.org/ can publish your maps for offline use. Geopublisher is a Desktop software that allows you to plug together vector and raster data and create digital maps. Then you can export this map as a stand-alone Java application. It even creates autostart files etc. and does not require a Java installation on the targeted computers.

***UPDATE 2018:* Geopublisher is not actively developed anymore.**

Comment: note: The destination is in German even though the url is to the English language version of the site. To fix locate the [english] link in the left hand navigation column.