# Setup a map server that runs from USB to whatever computer it is connected?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, wms

I would like to have a USB that I can bring with me to any computer. That USB should hold a map server, so that the client computer won't need internet and avoid using OSM or Google Maps or any other online map service.

I have another portable application that requests a WMS service to load maps, but I would like to direct that import to my local USB map/WMS server. Is PortableGIS the solution? I am using PortableGIS for QGIS and that works fine. However I can't find any documentation...

Comment: Which OS will you plug the USB ken in? Do you need it to be cross platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offline tiled map web app](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/offline-tiled-map-web-app)

Comment: Which client software would consume the WMS? Wouldn't it be easier maybe to just transport a QGIS project with all its data files?

Answer (score 2):

Consider OSGEO Live (Xubuntu) with USB bootable:
http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/usb_quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this tool last week:

https://github.com/imincik/mapfile-viewer

it is a fully featured, self hosted WxS service based on mapserver and python mapscript. It does not require a web server because it has one embedded.

As long as you Python-fu is strong it should not be too hard to set it up so that it can run from an USB key (even on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I have previously done this with [MS4W](http://maptools.org/ms4w/), though this only works on Windows